# Is there a name for a pattern where the previous asynchronous action is being automatically cancelled when a new action starts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, terminology, cancellation

It's common for the user to try to do something before the previous long-running action has finished. This could lead to multiple actions racing to mutate application state.

One simple solution is to cancel all actions but the last one.

Does it have a name?

The closest question I could find was the one about [cancelling the previous action when a new action happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205245/how-to-cancel-execution-of-a-previous-action-upon-a-new-action), but both the author and the answers only talk about implementation.

redux-saga has [takeLatest](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Concurrency.html#takelatest) (mentioned in the question above) which does more or less the same thing, but operates on saga tasks. The name "takeLatest" doesn't seem to be common anywhere else or reference anything.

Example implementation:

```js
class AsyncActionSlot {
  // Cancellable promises used only to make this example simpler.
  private _promise: BluebirdPromise<string> | null = null;

  // Can be useful to check if the last process has
  // already finished running. Not used anywhere
  // else in this example.
  public get isBusy(): boolean {
    return this._promise !== null;
  }

  public cancel(): void {
    if (this._promise) {
      this._promise.cancel();
      this._promise = null;
    }
  }

  public do(promise: Promise<string>, callback: (msg: string) => void): void {
    this.cancel();

    this._promise = Bluebird.resolve(promise);
    this._promise.then((msg) => {
      this._promise = null;
      callback(msg);
    });
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```js
const slot = new AsyncActionSlot();

// will be cancelled, won't print `'hello'`
slot.do(fetchHello(), console.log);

// will print `'world'`
slot.do(fetchWorld(), console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's any industry-wide term for this, but I would just think of it as "overriding", e.g. in your case I might go with `AsyncOverridingActionSlot()` (although that's a bit of a mouthful).

Alternatively, going back to the dictionary now, "supersede" seems to be an even more appropriate term, [defined by the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/supersede) as "to replace something, especially something older or more old-fashioned". So you could maybe go with something like `AsyncSupersedingActionSlot()`, or perhaps change the method name to `slot.supersedeDo()`.